# How to show items in dropdown based on alphabet search from Model in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Just like Stackoverflow Tags auto-complete dropdown,

I have a model of name Tags which contains 68311 `name` of Tags and `key` which contains the first alphabet it starts with.
**Note ** : There are few words which starts with dot (.) for example, (.post) in that case, we will consider the second alphabet.

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.key:
            if self.name.startswith('.'):
                self.key = self.name[1].upper()
            else:
                self.key = self.name[0].upper()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['name'])
```

Following is the view I am using to search the possible words starts with the user specified alphabet.

```
def tag_search(request):
    search_term = request.GET.get('search', '')
    print("search_term", search_term)
    
    if search_term.startswith('.'):
        search_term = search_term[1].upper()
    else:
        search_term = search_term[0].upper()
    
    tags = Tags.objects.filter(name__istartswith=search_term).values_list('name', flat=True)
    return JsonResponse({'tags': list(tags)})
```

When I try to input any character from frontend on the auto=-complete dropdown, It executes `tag_search` only once and provide the words which contains first character that the user provider.

What I required is when the user delete the first character and delete and type another one, then it should not show the result of previous written character.
For example, I refreshed the page, and in auto-complete dropdown I typed `P`, then it starts showing results related with `P` then I chosen a word and then tried to search next by typing `R` then it should show me the results of words for R. But using the following code, it is showing me results of firstly typed character that is `P`.

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <span class="pf-title">Tags <span style="color: red;">*</span></span>
    <div class="pf-field">
         {{ form.tags | add_class:'tags_input' }}
    </div>
</div>

<script>

$(function() {
    var data = [];

    $(".tags_input").on('input', function() {
        var search_term = $(this).val();
        
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'forum_app:tag_search' %}",
            method: "GET",
            data: { search: search_term },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                data = response.tags;
                updateTagComplete();
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

    function updateTagComplete() {
        $(".tags_input").tagComplete({
            keylimit: 1,
            hide: false,
            autocomplete: {
                data: data
            }
        });
    }

});

</script>
```

Auto-complete dropdown reference : https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: I think your need like this ??

https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20220605210853/output.gif

Comment: @Mahammadhusainkadiwala Yes you're right. Everything in frontend working fine. If I select any option in the dropdown it is properly selected as a block. But the problem I am facing will populating options in dropdown from the model based on the alpabet the user input so that all the other options considering words with that alphabet filter and appearing in option.

Comment: if I am not wrong....

your need when the user types in the dropdown then should be auto filter alphabetically

Comment: like this ....

https://codepen.io/riyos94/pen/VyBdBz